# Group isomorphism for deck transformation in covering space.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

When reading Lee's book, I encountered the following exercise:

> Let $\mathcal{P}\colon M\rightarrow G\backslash M$ be the covering arising
>   from a free and proper discrete group action of $G$ on $M$ and suppose $M$
>   is *connected*. Let $\Gamma_G:=\{l_g\in \text{Diff}(M):g\in G\}$,
>   then $G$ is isomorphic to $\Gamma_G$ by the obvious map $g\mapsto l_g$
>   and furthermore $\Gamma_G= \text{Deck}(\mathcal{P})$

I have two questions:

(1) Why do we need $M$ to be connected? I think the conclusion is obvious and does not involve connectedness of $M$.

(2) There is no assumption that the discrete group action is *smooth*, so isn't $\Gamma_G$ the empty set? Or we can deduce smoothness of the action from the connectedness of $M$?

Comment: There is an implicit assumption that the group acts smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $M=\mathbb R\sqcup\mathbb R\sqcup\mathbb R$ is the disjoint union of three copies of $\mathbb R$, and that $G$ is a cyclic group of order $3$ acting which permutes the copies transitively. Then $M/G=\mathbb R$. Can you see what the group of covering transformations $M\to M/G$ is?

Comment: It is $S^3$? So $\Gamma_G$ and $\text{Deck}(\mathcal{P})$ are not isomorphic.. But I can't come up with an rigorous argument why connectness is important here, any hint?.

Comment: Try to construct more examples and see if you can see a pattern. Where do the *extra* covering transformations come from in my example?

Comment: I can feel that there is an extra permutation upon the different connect component in the covering. But... It hard to argue rigorously...

Comment: Oh I see.. I just need to argue that connectedness is sufficient.. not need to prove it is necessary...

Comment: Sorry, I found my previous thought was wrong. Consider following condition: let $M$ be $S^1$, and $G$ be 3-order cyclic group of rotation 1, $2\pi/3,4\pi/3$. Then Diff($M$) is $S_3$, which is not isomorphic to $G$...but $M$ is connected. any problem?

Comment: $Diff(M)$ in that example is certainly not $S_3$.

Comment: OK...I will think over more..